# Dashboard left bar links are not working

Tags: magento2

I don't know what it happened.My dashboard left bar links are not working.Admin dashboard is looking ok, loading time is ok, but left bar is not working.

I run all commands

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento static-content
bin/magento indexer
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: What you see on browser console?